# Buggy Collapsible Header Tabs in React Native (Android)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I am trying to build a collapsible header tab.

I finally found this one [Collapsible Header Tabs Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@mattx/collapsible-header-tabs) which worked perfectly as base code. It worked as expected on IOS, but I had not confirmed the Android version yet. now that I look at it, it's very buggy. This can be seen in the above snack by running in android.

[image: Screen preview]

The Header scroll is very buggy (fluctuation) until the tabs clamp onto the top but then the scroll is smooth.
I am guessing that there is a problem with the sticky scroll which has animated scroll views and animated views.

I tried adding 
`scrollToOverflowEnabled = {true} overScrollMode={'never'}` but it didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by changing the input range from x to x*2.

```
const translateY = this.props.screenProps.scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange:  [0, headerHeight],
  outputRange: [0, headerHeight],
  extrapolate: "clamp",
})
```

changed to

```
const translateY = this.props.screenProps.scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange:  [0, headerHeight * 2],
  outputRange: [0, headerHeight],
  extrapolate: "clamp",
})
```

One of the explanations I found was that the offset given by iOS is a series like 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 but android gives offset in decimal values.

I don’t know how changing input range as x*2 solves that or if it’s even a reason, but it did run smoothly later on.

But even though the stuttering problem was solved, there were still some problems with scrolling on Android. So I had to drop this.